# Trouble using Linksys WPC54G ver. 3.1 in Dell Inspirion 5100 with Lubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, dell

I'm new to linux. I've read several posts and tried several suggestions but nothing seems to help the specific hardware I'm using. I'm using a Linksys WPC54G version 3.1, which is a PCMCIA network adapter and a Dell Inspirion 5100 laptop computer. After installation, the wired internet connection works but when I try some of the suggestions I've found to set up the wireless connection, the wired connection drops and I'm unable to re-establish it. This is the fourth time I've reinstalled Lubuntu. Please help.

Comment: The results in terminal of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `lshw -c net` `lsusb` if it is a USB wifi helps us more to find a solution

Comment: @jmw90 Can you elaborate a bit on the problem, like what do you mean by "dumps"?, and does it work before you try those things? You'll also need to identify the exact model of the NIC, as there is nothing specific about it in the title. Please add the output of `lspci` to the question.

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net using LSTerminal yields 02:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401 100Base-T [14e4:4401] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Device [4401:1028]
 Kernel driver in use: b44
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Linksys WPC54G v3 802.11g Wireless-G Notebook Adapter [1737:0048]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: And lshw -c net lsusb, also using LXTerminal yields Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.16
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

 -version        print program version (B.02.16)

format can be
 -html           output hardware tree as HTML
 -xml            output hardware tree as XML
 -short          output hardware paths
 -businfo        output bus information

options can be
 -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
 -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
 -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
 -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )

Comment: -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
 -quiet          don't display status
 -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
 -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your card has a Broadcom chip, which the b43 driver runs just fine.  HOwever, the firmware for the chip must be installed by you.  These days, I think the b43-fwcutter package will do the fw install, formerly the linux-firmware-nonfree contained the firmware.  Search this site for Broadcom problems, there are many solutions, but look to the newest ones.

---

Using the wired connection:
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter

That should do it.  You should see the wireless icon (a pile of arcs) in the top bar, and a left click on it should show the nearby access points.  Click on yours, enter your password, and you should get a connection.  Maybe better to disconnect the wired connection first.
The firmware used to be in linux-firmware-nonfree, but it had been removed the last time I looked.

Comment: As I've mentioned, I'm new to linux. Additionally, I've tried several suggestions from posts I've found. All ended with losing my internet connection on the laptop altogether. So if someone would please elaborate on what I need to do, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Copied and pasted "sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter" into LXTerminal as you advised. It appeared to install something however I don't have a top bar and no icon appeared in the bottom bar. Please advise.